# Need to get results between two dates in Room, but returns null

Tags: android, date, kotlin, android-room, mpandroidchart

I'm making a candlestick chart using `MPAndroidChart` lib and getting data from `Room` db. I store `date : Date`, `hr: Int` in the database. I'm trying to get result between specified date interval. I've written a query that goes `"SELECT * FROM hr_data WHERE date BETWEEN :dateStart AND :dateEnd"` however I always get null. I tried having the parameters as `Date` as well as `long`, but still the same result.

I'm using a typeconverter so in my data class I pass `Date` type for the date.

Code:

`MyDao.kt` :

```
...

@Query("SELECT * FROM hr_data WHERE date BETWEEN :dateStart AND :dateEnd")
fun readHearRateBetweenDates(dateStart: Date, dateEnd: Date): LiveData<List<HeartRate>>

...
```

**I've changed to `Long` instead of `Date` and same result.**

`Repository.kt` :

```
...

fun readHeartRateBetweenDates(dateStart: Date, dateEnd: Date) : LiveData<List<HeartRate>> = myDao.readHeartRateBetweenDates(dateStart, dateEnd)

...
```

`HeartRateViewModel.kt` :

```
...

fun readHeartRateBetweenDates(dateStart: Date, dateEnd: Date) : LiveData<List<HeartRate>> = repository.readHeartRateBetweenDates(dateStart, dateEnd)

...
```

`HeartRateActivity.kt` :

```
...

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
...
 Log.i(TAG, "DATA - ${
   viewModel.readHeartRateBetweenDates(
     1628632376254,
     1628692326964
     ).value
   }"
 }

viewModel.readHeartRateBetweenDates(1628632376254, 1628692326964).observe(this, Observer {
            if (it.isNullOrEmpty()){
                Log.i(TAG, "IS NULL OR EMPTY: $it")
            } else
                Log.i(TAG, "NOT NULL: $it")
        })

...
```

I print it out in console just to see the result and the result is always `null`.

I've checked the query in https://www.sqliteonline.com and it works as it returns two results.

When I read all of the data, since it doesn't require any parameters, I just use a variable
`val readAllData : LiveData<List<HeartRate>> = repository.readAllData()`. **And I'm mentioning this because if I put my between dates query inside the one where I'm getting all of the data and just hardcode the values like `"SELECT * FROM hr_data WHERE date BETWEEN 1628632376254 AND 1628692326964"` I do get correct results. Only when I use a function with parameters it gets me `null`**

Comment: In which formate are you storing the date values? There is nothing wrong with the query. You should pass the same formate in which you are storing. My suggestion is to store the date in String & pass params in String. It will be easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the database inspector to check if your database is populated (always nice to double check it)
https://developer.android.com/studio/inspect/database

But I believe that your problem is the liveData. LiveData will only emit value as only it is observed, so when you call

> viewModel.readHeartRateBetweenDates(
> 1628632376254,
> 1628692326964
> ).value

It will always return null.

What you should do instead is

```
viewModel.readHeartRateBetweenDates(1628632376254,1628692326964).observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            //do whatever you want with the value returned 
    }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for a quick answer. I've done it with observing as well, still null.

`viewModel.readHeartRateBetweenDates(1628632376254, 1628692326964).observe(this, Observer {
            if (it.isNullOrEmpty()){
                Log.i(TAG, "IS NULL OR EMPTY: $it")
            } else
                Log.i(TAG, "NOT NULL: $it")
        })`

Comment: have you use the database inspector to check whether the values are populated?!

Comment: Yeah they are populated correctly. As I already display ALL the data I get, it's just that I can't get the specific data between two dates

Comment: what does it happen if you change ur query to something like "WHERE date > :dateStart"? Still null?!

Comment: I think the query is correct as I tested it outside of the app as well as inside (read the last paragraph of my question), I think the problem might be calling it wrong or something like that, I just can't figure it out

Comment: I belive your query is correct as well, however what you are trying to SELECT is wrong (I guess), like you said you have a type converter, but you are passing a LONG in the method.. maybe that is the issue? You have to pass Date in the query?
Also, maybe you can save everything as Milliseconds?!
My idea here is that you make it as simple as possible and go from there.

Comment: As mentioned in my post, I have tried both LONG and DATE type values, both giving the same result - NULL